# Newtheoremstyle: start counting at 0

Tags: numbering, theorems

I defined a `\newtheoremstyle` and I want it to start counting at 0 instead of 1. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is interesting, but you should add more information, for example the code for the new theorem style and the package you're using (**ntheorem** or **amsthm**).

Answer (score 5):

Both [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) defines `\newtheoremstyle` to declare a new theorem style with each having very different interfaces. However, both define the counter associated with a new theorem environment in a similar way. In both instances, setting the counter to `-1` after the declaration but before the first usage, or in the document preamble, initializes it to start at `0`.

#### `amsthm`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm

\newtheoremstyle{lemmastyle}% <name>
  {3pt}% <Space above>
  {3pt}% <Space below>
  {}% <Body font>
  {}% <Indent amount>
  {\itshape}% <Theorem head font>
  {:}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}% <Space after theorem head>
  {}% <Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')>
\theoremstyle{lemmastyle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} \setcounter{lemma}{-1}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lemma}
\lipsum[2]
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

#### `ntheorem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{ntheorem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{lemmastyle}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}% no optional argument
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}% optional argument
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{lemmastyle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} \setcounter{lemma}{-1}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lemma}
\lipsum[2]
\end{lemma}
\end{document}​
```

However, if your newly-defined theorem is synchronized with (a slave to) another counter (the master counter), like that of (say) `\chapter` or `\section`, then some more work needs to be done in order to reset it to `-1` (rather than `0`) at every master counter increment.

In both instances [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to provide dummy text *Lorem ipsum* style.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It was the command \setcounter, that I was lacking. It helped a lot!

Comment: @kika: if you find this answer best solves your problem, please don't forget accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Works also for lists `\setcounter{enumi}{-1}`. Thanks!