# Forcing \ref output

Tags: cross-referencing

I am referencing a label like this `texttext \ref{p:1}, \ref{p:2} text` and after compiling my document I always get an output like this **"texttext 8, 9 text"**.

Is there a way I can force an output like **"texttext 1, 2 text"**?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I get the idea that you use `\label` where you want to use `\ref`.

Comment: Oh sorry i fixed that.

Comment: The numbers that come out are the numbers used in whatever you have labeled, do you want the section number to be "8" but the reference to that section to be "1" ?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  In this case it would go a long way towards clarifying the question and also serve as a test case to ensure that the solutions provided actually work for your particular case.

Comment: @David Carlise I want to reference items in `\begin{description}` list which don't have any numbers, but the ones i manualy specified.

Comment: How were we to guess that:-) That is why we always ask people to supply a full example. If you use enumerate rather than description, the numbering is automatic and \ref will pick up the numbering, If that doesn't do what you want, edit your question with a complete example see the link in Peter's comment.

Comment: Related Question/Duplicate? [Custom Enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47335/custom-enumeration/47336#47336)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to refer to some label and choose your own text for the reference, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[42] \phantomsection\label{p:1}Some text.

\item[2010] \phantomsection\label{p:2}Some more text.
\end{description}

Arbitrary numbers for the items.

\newpage

texttext \hyperref[p:1]{p:1}, \hyperref[p:2]{p:2} text

\end{document}
```

where `\hyperref`'s `[...]` contains the label's name and `{...}` the text to be displayed for the reference.
The `\phantomsection`s are necessary, else the hyperlinks will aim at the beginning of the `description`.
When the `hyperref` package is used, at least two compier runs are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\deflabel[1]{\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
\newcommand\mylabel[1]{#1\deflabel{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\mylabel{foo}\label{l:1}]  bar
\item[\mylabel{baz}\label{l:2}]  quux
\end{description}

See \ref{l:1} and \ref{l:2},
```