# Enumerate with custom strings

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to get a list of custom labels. Here is what I've tried:

```
\begin{enumerate}[Exercise (1)]

\item first

\item second

\end{enumerate}
```

This results in each item being labeled as: `Exerc#se (#)`

Where `#` is the number of the item in the list. How can I make the "i" in exercise not be pattern matched?

Using a `\` doesn't work, it causes syntax error.

Comment: Are you using the `enumerate` package or `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option. Please provide a compilable document!

Comment: I am using the `enumerate` package. Thank you for the help

Comment: please always use a complete document, so people don't have to guess.

Comment: Use `\begin{enumerate}[{Exercise} (1)]` ...

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld: Too late ... David Carlisle has answered already ... he seems to have more insight into `enumerate` than I have  -- very strange ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry:-) excellent package, don't you agree?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Some say so... :D

Comment: for the case you have, my old enumerate package is fine, but in general enumitem as in @ChristianHupfer's answer is rather more flexible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But `enumerate` works with `beamer` (as far as I know), but `enumitem` works very poorly with `beamer`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47335/custom-enumeration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in the package documentation, letters inside `{}` are never taken as counter templates so

```
 [{Exercise }(1)]
```

should hide `Exercise`

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, here's a possible way to solve this with `enumitem` (a little bit more complex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[font={\bfseries},label={Exercise (\arabic*)}]

\item first

\item second

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from a version without `font={\bfseries}`