# Changing numbering in enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

I am currently making a test that contains 10 questions for easy, average and difficult. Can you help me modify the numbering into like this:

EASY ROUND

E1.

E2.

E3.

.

.

.

E10.

AVERAGE ROUND

A1.

A2.

and so on.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350087/enumerate-with-custom-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `enumerate` should help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

EASY ROUND

\begin{enumerate}[E1]
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}

AVERAGE ROUND

\begin{enumerate}[{A}1] %{A} is important -- PS
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}

(compare with):

\begin{enumerate}[A1]
\item
\item
\item

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here  is how to do it with `enumitem`:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
............
\begin{document}
............
\begin{enumerate[label=E\arabic*.]
\item ......
\end{enumerate}
```

If you load `enumitem` with option `[shortlabels]`, you also can code

```
\begin{enumerate[E1.]
```